# Youtube movie upload from multiple iOS clients to a specific youtube channel

Tags: youtube-api

I am creating a quote for an iOS application, and one of the requirements is to be able to upload a movie file (created by the application itself) to a specific youtube channel owned by the client.

So the users of this application will be creating movie content of their own, and then optionally uploading it to a channel owned by the client.

I have been looking over the youtube api, and the examples and documentation appear to be centred around users uploading movies to their own youtube account, thereby requiring that they go through the OAUTH process.

One approach that does seem as if it would work is to have the iOS application upload their movies to a server that we own, and then have that server upload them to youtube.

This feels reasonable, although a little cumbersome and wasteful of bandwidth.  Ideally the movies would go straight to the client's channel.

My question is whether this is possible?

Comment: Asking for a recommended approach is asking for opinions and discussion, which doesn't fit our format. I took the liberty of editing your question down to the specifics that do fit the format. If you disagree with my edits, you can undo them or flag the question to have a moderator take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check the  TOS (terms of service) wether it is disallowed. See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

Is this possible ? It seems others are already doing so. See:

- [Google API Ruby Client - single user with OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493116/google-api-ruby-client-single-user-with-oauth-2-0)
- [Youtube API : Upload videos to a specific channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951065/youtube-api-upload-videos-to-a-specific-channel/14983623#14983623)

NOTE:

- You may encounter usage limits sooner; Check your API console for usage counters.
- You are responsible for what others are uploading to your channel. In terms of disallowed content. An option is to have someone checking what everyone is uploading, before making it public.